# Flask-SQLAlchemy. AttributeError: module '<...>.db' has no attribute 'Model'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

so I have one module called 'co'.

Here is it's __init__.py

```
...
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
...
```

And models.py

```
...
from co import db
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
...
```

Running `flask db init` is giving me

> AttributeError: module 'co.db' has no attribute 'Model'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: error is because you don't hava file called co.

Comment: Is the db = ... in the `__init__.py` file or in the `co.py` file? Have you tried moving the db assignment to the` co.py` file?

Answer (score 0):

This would imply you have the following folder structure

```
root
 - co
   - __init__.py
   - models.py
   - routes.py
 - myapp.py
```